# How to continue a SWF rendering whilst off screen?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I need to be able to continue rendering a SWF file whilst it is off screen or minimized. Taken from the adobe website: "This is an automatic feature in Flash Player since version 10.1. Flash Player minimizes processing when SWF content goes off-screen."

I have extensively searched around for a solution on this. One solution suggested was to use the HTML parameter "hasPriority" and set it to true which will ensure some things are not paused. SWF content will stop rendering regardless of this when off screen or hidden.

Does anyone know if it is possible to disable this automatic feature so my SWF will continue to render off screen?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I don't believe that controlling this is possible. What is the goal of off-screen rendering? Perhaps a different solution can be offered based on what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I agree here. If you are not trying to capture a live screen video, there is likely an alternative solution that you do not need offscreen rendering for.

Comment: I am basically building a slot machine that has auto spinning functionality. It was requested that the machine continues to spin whilst minimized or off screen. I'll have to find another work around. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flash virtual machine is specifically designed so that, while viewing flash in the browser, the VM is paused when the instance of the player loses window focus. This is necessary functionality in order to... well.. keep flash from utterly destroying your computer, forcing it catch ablaze and send it to the computer underworld. Just imagine what would happen if you had 3-4 flash sites open and rendering off screen on your tablet. It would die a horrible death. You cannot override this functionality.

Comment: Is there a way to detect in Flash if it has stopped rendering when off screen?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. The entire point of the feature is to completely suspend execution of all code.

Comment: Wow can you ever tell that I wrote this a long time ago: "rendering off screen on your tablet" - Must have been before flash died. On that note, I'd recommend switching whatever you're doing over to HTML5 capabilities. You can accomplish 90% of what flash can do at least. Look at things like the google swiffy plugin. Has almost full actionscript 3 support. I tested it the other day and used third party flash libs, they compiled fine.

Comment: This way with swiffy, you can still design in the flash IDE and code in actionscript, it just gets exported to HTML5. It's pretty good, has performance limitations etc. But, take it from someone who loved flash so much that I'm re-writing the whole of flash capabilities in 3 different languages: flash is dead, stop investing in it.

Comment: Sadly TE, your out of touch. Flash is still alive and well. I did find my answer in flash player 11.2. You can detect when rendering was suspended via the throttling event.

Comment: @tree Okay, glad you found your answer. I'm so out of touch, that's why every community evangelist for flash abandoned it over 2 years ago. Huge names in the community like Joa Ebert full on denounced adobe and flash. Adobe open sourced the entire flex SDK, a part of the runtime that is more than twice as large as the core flash API.